Amplifier IC circuit
I am trying to reuse an amplifier (CD2822A) from a small clock radio as well as all the pasive components required to drive it from that radio
Schematic of this amplifier chip is here: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/sLh9dLPd#link
Sadly its only in chinese, but I did find that this amplifier is a clone of ST TDA2822 which has schematic in english
Now since, I want to amplifiy mono signal (for now, in the future I will add stereo) I natuarly assumed I would use only 1 pair of inputs, but looking at the BTL 应用线路 (BTL Application Circuit) (page6) schematic

they used some kind of bridge configuration (why?)
Is it better for me to use one pair of inputs if I want to add stereo in the future?
I will try to reuse all the components from the radio itself (8ohm speaker, all the pasive componnents, volume potentiometer as well as I will use 4.5V to power the amp, just like the radio does), the onlything I cannot use from the radio is the schematic, because for this Scott CX81 clock radio, I cannot find it anywhere
What confuses me also is why is there no potentiometer in schematic, how are u suppose to control the volume of this amplifier?

Please embed the schematic image into your question.

@Andyaka low-rep user can't do that directly

honest question: The TDA2822 is already a "crap amplifier", as far as I can tell. I'm pretty sure a clone of that won't be any better (in fact, harmonic distortion seems to be more than twice as bad, and that wasn't really acceptable to begin with). I wonder: what's the goal of this reuse?

well, since I already have it, its more for testing that anything, else (have a couple of detector radios outputing low level signal I would like to amplify just to confirm the circuit works
